# Change background color of vi/vim

Tags: vimrc

I don't have access to the vimrc (no write access that is)

So far I have been using

```
colorscheme desert
```

to be able to read comments. But i'm getting tired of it any workaround or do I have to beg sysadmin to chmod it?

Comment: When you say "the" vimrc what are you talking about?  You know you can have your own vimrc in your home directory right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make it permanent, you should add that to your `~/.vimrc` file. That's a personal vimrc, as opposed to the system wide one that you're probably looking at. The syntax is slightly different, so what you would do is add the line

```
colors desert
```

to your local config file, again that's `~/.vimrc` and you're good to go.

Comment: +1 that. (Also if you have a 256 colour xterm, then `desert256` is a good scheme.)

Comment: I don't have desert256 unfortunately installed but thanks :)